# C++ Lambda reference vs copy

Tags: c++, lambda

I thought both `valueLambda` and `refLambda` function both execute after x=13; but turn out `valueLambda` cout 1. So how does it work behind the scene? I thought `valueLambda` and `refLambda` are just `std::function` which does not store memory?

```
int main() {

    int x = 1;
    auto valueLambda = [=]() { std::cout << x << std::endl; };
    auto refLambda = [&]() { std::cout << x << std::endl; };
    x = 13;
    valueLambda();
    refLambda();
}
```

Comment: So OP, what do you think `=` and `&` mean?

Comment: (This is somewhat a simplification, but a useful working understanding) Lambdas are just classes with fields for each variable they capture and an operator() for the function call.   they work just like any other object.  If you capture by value, it makes a complete internal copy of the variable,  if you capture by reference, it makes an internal reference -- just like if you typed out the class longhand yourself.  class L{int const x; L(int x):x(x){} operator()(){cout<<x<<endl;}}  swap out int & x; for int const x; for capture by reference.

Comment: ok, I see. so the lambda type can store value. wakakaka so amature